# Allow anonymous access when using OpenID Connect and Azure App Registration

Tags: azure, openid-connect, openid

I can see that there is a setting for anonymous access when configuring a web app service in Azure but I can't find a comparable setting within Azure Active Directory app registration settings.

Is there a setting you can add to the manifest that will mean that Azure will return to the redirect URL even if the login is unsuccessful?

I notice that currently it doesn't even redirect back on logout and I would expect it to redirect ideally. We can potentially also use Azure B2C or I could potentially just set it up as an app service but really just struggling to navigate the documentation as it doesn't seem to be a well documented scenario.

Ideally there would be an option on the first landing page to not login and return to site. The same option would appear on an unsuccessful login attempt so that the user always has the option to simply not log in. Our application is able to handle both anonymous and authenticated replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such a setting does not exist.
Azure AD will only return a token if the user authenticates successfully.

You will need to rethink how you want to handle this.
You could for example have a page on your app side that gives the user two options: Sign in / Continue without signing in.